# Python: How to manipulate imported text

Tags: python, text

I have  a text file that looks like that:

```
1, balab,la.1    
2, bal,abla2
3, bal,a.bla3
```

How can I import the text and the first numbers into different variables ?

```
numb_list = [1,2,3]
text = [balabla1,balabla2,balabla3]
```

Comment: Where can I find such a tutorial ?

Comment: This is not that basic ! Haha

Comment: This is a compound issue, to go from a file to strings in python is one part, to split a string up is another, putting the split parts into lists is a third.  There is no way to answer your question in a way that would help future viewers since all three of those parts are well answered elsewhere.  *go look for the solution to each part, if you run into a __specific__ issue then post a question*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through the `lines` and `split` on the `comma` (`,`). Then append the first part (the number) to `numb_list` but first convert to an int with `int()`. Then append the second part (remember this is index `1` so got with `[1]`) to the `text` list, but first stripping off the `space` at the start.

```
numb_list = []
text = []

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        parts = l.split(",")
        numb_list.append(int(parts[0]))
        text.append(parts[1].strip())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! However I get the error: name 'strip' is not defined

Comment: @totyped Sorry about that, I couldn't test it and got that bit the wrong way around!

Comment: @totyped No problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
numb_list = list()
text = list()
with open("file.txt") as fl:
    for line in fl:
        n, t = line.strip().split(", ")
        numb_list.append(int(n))
        text.append(t.replace(".", "").replace(",", ""))
```

Comment: I get the error: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: check value in n. Before numb_list.append(int(n)) add line print(n). Is it number?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/test.csv', header=None)

numb_list = df.ix[:,0].tolist()
text_list = df.ix[:,1].tolist()
```

**Output**

[1, 2, 3]

[' balabla1', ' balabla2', ' balabla3']